# Master page post back on click of menu item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page wherein I have menu list. When I click on any of the menu item my entire page gets post back. I do not want this to happen. 
Instead I want only the content that needs to be refreshed/change.

Any quick / easy resolution to the above issue?

Please help.

Comment: And how will you know what content needs refreshed?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: IFrame with a tags and modify the Target argument.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need to leverage an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). I can't feasibly build an example here but that link will walk you through an exhaustive explanation. It will make it possible for you to simply update the content that needs changes rather than the entire page. Another really obvious reason I can't feasibly build an example here is because your question doesn't contain enough information to do that.